# tomcat 7 failed to start from within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying to do a `run as...run on server` of a spring mvc web app from within eclipse, and I am getting the following dialog box error:

[image]

Can someone show me how to fix this?

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: list of lotsa files with their paths.
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:KnowledgeManager' did not find a matching property.
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 637 ms
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start      
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/KnowledgeManager]]  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/KnowledgeManager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 21 more
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 18, 2014 2:03:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Here is the spring-context dependency as it is written in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I also did a `maven update project`, a `maven download sources`, and an `eclipse clean project`, but none of those things have fixed this problem.

What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the cause of the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
```

You should add `spring-context` and all the jars that this artifact depends on to the classpath of your project, Ex:
     
            org.springframework
            spring-context
            ${org.springframework.version}

**EDIT:**

Right click your project -> properties -> Deployment Assembly and verify that your project dependencies are deployed to WEB-INF/lib:

[image]

**EDIT:**

What really resolved the problem:
**right click** on server(in the servers view of eclipse) -> **clean** + **publish**.

Comment: That dependency is already in my pom.xml with the identical syntax.  I also just did a `maven update project`, a `maven download source` and an `eclipse clean project`, but the `class not found` error is persisting.  Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: Thank you for looking deeper.  I just added a screen shot of my eclipse deployment assembly to my original posting above.  Any other ideas?

Comment: right click the server in the servers view and mabe a simple clean + publish will resolve the problem. i don't see any other solution to this problem. Are you sure that maven have downloaded all the needed dependencies?

Comment: +1 and Thank you. I tried the right click on server and then a `clean`, and then `publish`, and then tried `run as...run on server` again and the app is loading with an unrelated error that I plan to work out separately.  I am marking yours as the answer, but others might find the solution more easily if you add your most recent suggestion as an edit to your answer.

Comment: I have another question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414314/unable-to-find-column-with-logical-name-of-embeddedid

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem. the problem was occurred because common logging .jar file was not added in my project build path. after adding it project works fine.

Comment: I cannot confirm your answer. However, thank you and +1 for adding insight into this old question.

Answer (score 1):

that stack trace clearly says `ClassNotFoundException`

It seems that `Spring-context.jar` is not found in your class path.

Try adding that jar in your class path first.

Comment: +1 and Thank you for trying to help.  The solution to the problem was to right click on server in eclipse then do clean+publish.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see the spring jars in the "Maven Dependencies" section on the project?

If not, you can have a problem in your pom dependencies definition, or maybe update project didn't complete successfully. Try check dependencies definition and run update project again.

If so, did you try "clean..., "clean work directory" and "publish" on your server?

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 and Thank you for trying to help.  The solution to the problem was to right click on server in eclipse then do clean+publish.

Answer (score 0):

Check your url pattern in web.xml 
/webapp/*
replace "webapp" with your path name

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem because of dependencies which are available in pom.xml file,some of them are corrupted.I resolve that by simply removing .m2/repository folder contents and followed this steps.

1. Run as -> Maven clean.
2. Run as -> Maven Install.(Use good internet provider).
3. maven -> Update project.

Hope it will help you too.