# unable to find column with logical name of @embeddedid

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

In a Spring MVC app using hibernate and JPA, I am trying to set up a mapping for an entity whose underlying data table has a two-column primary key.  **How can I alter my code below to get it to work?**

I created an EmbeddedId called `conceptPK`, but I am getting the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: 
Unable to find column with logical name: conceptPK 
in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(sct2_concept) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

In the entity class, I set up the primary key with the following code:

```
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="id")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="effectiveTime", column=@Column(name="effectiveTime"))
})
private ConceptPK conceptPK;
```

The embedded ConceptPK class is as follows:

```
@Embeddable
class ConceptPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    protected BigInteger id;

    @Column(name="effectiveTime", nullable=false)
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime effectiveTime;

    /** getters and setters **/
    public DateTime getEffectiveTime(){return effectiveTime;}
    public void setEffectiveTime(DateTime ad){effectiveTime=ad;}

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {this.id = id;}
    public BigInteger getId() {return id;}
}
```

For easier reading, I have uploaded the complete code and the complete stack trace to a file sharing site rather than create an excessively long posting here.

You can read the complete code for `the class above` at the file sharing site [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/l0B9BFnMqR0k12AUZLQC?b=xeNzAwPNjiJFtqwqhP5Q).

You can read the code for `a second class` that references the first class [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/vfol0sQVbnNDazK9dvjT?b=azuXjALXe2dShdp6SUYo).

You can read the code for `a third class` that references the first class [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/bXF4J7169Zo4dTrege9F?b=df2pupZo5a7YCyvnDUYg).

You can read the `SQL code` that creates the underlying data tables [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/jRDJxhax0ViNZ3TmHpV0?b=RaPt2akaAkIlgArMt1lh).

You can read the complete stack trace at the file sharing site [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/kiG8Hap9Ttbuojkwtqc2?b=b5cTRMM4VQ1tt46oDZlF).

Comment: `ConceptPK` is an inner class?

Comment: @mabbas Yes.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: i can't see anything wrong in what you are doing but can you create a separate class and test if it resolves the problem?

Comment: @mabbas I created it as a separate class, but the error persists.  This class is referred to by two other classes, using `conceptPK`.  Would it help if I posted those classes too?

Comment: yes because i can't see any problem with the code you already posted.

Comment: @mabbas I just posted links to two other classes at the file sharing site, with links in my original posting above.

Comment: @mabbas I also just posted a link to the SQL code that creates the underlying tables in the database.  Does this help?

Comment: Why are you using the `@AttributeOverrides` annotation? It should be enough that your PK has the `@Column` annotations on its fields.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear Thank you.  I just commented out `@AttributeOverrides`, but I am still getting the same stack trace when I try to recompile the app.  Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: @CodeMed put `@Id` annotation into `protected BigInteger id;` and try.

Comment: @CodeMed The problem is in the second class you posted and exactly on this line `@JoinColumn(name="descriptionPK", referencedColumnName = "conceptPK")`. You can find how to make the join between 2 tables [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4865) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775055/hibernate-embeddedid-join).

Comment: I can't understand this question, because all external links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `SnomedDescription` Entity's `@ManyToOne` association to `SnomedConcept`.

For a start, this is not a ManyToOne, but in fact a OneToOne, as their primary keys are identical.

But the main problem is that the columns you've used in the `@JoinColumn` annotation for this association do not exist as database columns, so this will never work.

Instead, you should have join columns as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    @JoinColumn(name="effectiveTime", referencedColumnName="effectiveTime")
})
private SnomedConcept concept;
```

Now, you can carry on using the `@ManyToOne` for this relationship, but really you should be using the same embedded PK for both (`ConceptPK`), and then `SnomedDescription` will look more like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accesslogs")
public class SnomedDescription {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ConceptPK descriptionPK;

    @Column(name="active")
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name="moduleId")
    private BigInteger moduleid;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private SnomedConcept concept;

    ..... etc.
```

Yes, you can use the same PK embeddable in multiple Entities.

If it ***is*** a one-to-one relationship, then the association in `SnomedConcept` to `SnomedDescription` should also be one-to-one, with `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.

If the association between the two is optional, then the 'side' that is always there should define the one-to-one as `@OneToOne(optional=true)`. In other words, if there is always a Concept, but not always a Description, then the one-to-one in Concept should be defined as `@OneToOne(optional=true)`.

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to post such a well articulated answer.  Sometimes there is more than one `Description` for a given `Concept`, but there is always only one `Concept` for a given `Description`.  Does this change your advice regarding the `OneToOne` relationship?

Comment: How can there be more than one Description for a Concept? The `DescriptionPK`, which is the primary key for Description, only has 2 fields, `id` and `effectiveTime`. Are these not the same fields that are in the `ConceptPK`? Just looked at your SQL and it's very confusing. The Foreign Key from `sct2_description` to `sct2_concept` only mentions `id`. What about `effectiveTime`? Are these tables only linked by the `id`? In which case, what Concept does a Description refer to? And how?

Comment: There are other variables besides effective time which can lead to their own values for description for a given concept.  Thank you for pointing out a possible other key issue.  This is a third party database, and I am still studying it.  As I figure out how to make certain changes to it, there may be a delay in my propagation of similar changes to other parts of the app.

Comment: But according to your SQL, Description's primary key is made up of just id and effectiveTime. You will not be able to have multiple records for the same id and effectiveTime combination, otherwise you will get a constraint violation. Have you tried manually creating sample DB records with the tables you have created?

Comment: Look at the SQL that you have posted. Both `sct2_concept` and `sct2_description` have the same primary key definition: `PRIMARY KEY ('id','effectiveTime')`. How can there be multiple Descriptions for any Concept?

Answer (score 0):

Annotating the key as hown below solved the issue for me.

```
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
String name;
```